# Getting text before the cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

Suppose I type a paragraph with new lines such as,

```
Hey mr Nikhil
Howdy you
Funny$ life isn't it.
```

Now consider the dollar symbol as my cursor.
If I can print my text by this code,

```
print(self.toPlainText())
```

Then how can I get the text before the cursor so that my output will be,

```
Hey mr Nikhil
Howdy you
Funny
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the cursor position:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.te = QTextEdit()
        self.te.setPlainText('''Hey mr Nikhil\nHowdy you\nFunny life isn't it.''')
        lay.addWidget(self.te)
        button = QPushButton("Click Me")
        lay.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self):
        p = self.te.textCursor().position()
        result = self.te.toPlainText()[:p]
        print("result:\n{}".format(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```